# how to automatically align the axis limits for different ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running regression and presenting the results using ggplots. Generally, the intention is to see the dynamic effect of a policy that happened in period 2.

I am plotting the regression results, the dataframe I created from the regression functions looks like

```
dfplot1 <- data.frame(coef=c(0.05,0,0.1,0.15,0.2), 
                      se=c(0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1), 
                      period=1:5)
dfplot2 <- data.frame(coef=c(0.05,0,0.12,0.18,0.24), 
                      se=c(0.12,0,0.12,0.12,0.12), 
                      period=1:5)
```

And I plot the coefficients with standard errors using

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(dfplot1)+
  geom_point(aes(x=period, y=coef))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=period, xend=period, y=coef-1.96*se, yend=coef+1.96*se))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=period, xend=period, y=coef-1.96*se, yend=coef+1.96*se))+ 
  labs(x='Year', y='Coefficients')+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
p2 <- ggplot(dfplot2)+
  geom_point(aes(x=period, y=coef))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=period, xend=period, y=coef-1.96*se, yend=coef+1.96*se))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=period, xend=period, y=coef-1.96*se, yend=coef+1.96*se))+ 
  labs(x='Year', y='Coefficients')+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
p1|p2
```

The figure looks like,
[image]

I can use ylim in each ggplot to set the y axis limit and make them the same
like

```
p1+ylim(-0.5,0.5)
p2+ylim(-0.5,0.5)
```

[image]

To better visualize and compare the coefficients in these two regressions with different covariates, is there a way to **automatically** find the best fit and align the axes of the two ggplots?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe pass `range()` or sth similar to `ylim`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `facet_wrap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dfplot1 <- data.frame(coef=c(0.05,0,0.1,0.15,0.2), 
                      se=c(0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1), 
                      period=1:5)
dfplot2 <- data.frame(coef=c(0.05,0,0.12,0.18,0.24), 
                      se=c(0.12,0,0.12,0.12,0.12), 
                      period=1:5) 

df <- bind_rows(dfplot1, dfplot2, .id = "id")

df |> ggplot(aes(period, coef)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = period, y = coef - 1.96 * se, yend = coef + 1.96 * se)) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Coefficients") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
  facet_wrap(~id) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You can harvest the ranges from both plots using `layer_scales`, then get the overall `range` of the concatenated result to use in `ylim`. This avoids the need for guessing.

```r
lim <- range(c(layer_scales(p1)$y$range$range, layer_scales(p2)$y$range$range))

p1 + ylim(lim) | p2 + ylim(lim)
```

[image]

Comment: I personally think that's overkill. Why using calculated limits and an extra line of code if the scale is based on readily present data? simply `ylim = range(c(df1$coef, df2$coef))` should suffice. - or, better, as suggested by Carl, use facets... :)

Comment: It's a fair point @tjebo. The look of the plot changes quite a bit with facets, and this may not be what the OP wanted. Yes, one can set various theme elements to fix this, but that's even more code. I guess I'm approaching this from the perspective of having two complete ggplots already, but aligning both axes whether or not one has the original data - I thought that was an interesting question in its own right. Anyway, you're probably right that it's overkill for the task in hand. Post an answer with your suggestion - it might not have occurred to the OP.

Comment: actually, I just realised that there is a computation indeed (the estimated error) - thus I guess your approach isn't that overkill after all :D

Answer (score 1):

This one is similar almost same! to @Carl's+1. He was faster. The main feature in my point of view is using `bind_rows` with the `.id` argument. That let us use the `id` column for `facet_wrap` and the we can get a common y axis:

```
bind_rows(list(dfplot1 = dfplot1, dfplot2 = dfplot2), .id = 'id') %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=period, y=coef))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=period, xend=period, y=coef-1.96*se, yend=coef+1.96*se))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=period, xend=period, y=coef-1.96*se, yend=coef+1.96*se))+ 
  labs(x='Year', y='Coefficients')+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  facet_wrap(.~id)
```

[image]